# How do I put a notice reminder when somebody remove the powered on my theme footer

Tags: php

Example link on my footer

```
$powered = 'Powered by <a href="htp://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>';
```

theme file

```
<?php echo $powered; ?>
```

How to make if `$powered` removed from my footer and the error/reminder notice it.

Example `die('Do not remove the powered link')`

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's to stop someone removing the reminder too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer:

```
<?php

$powered = 'Powered by <a href="htp://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>';

ob_start();
echo $powered;
$html = ob_get_clean();

/*
 * If you remove the "echo $powered;" part, please don't remove the following lines
 * so I can detect the license violation. Thank you for your cooperation!
 */
if( strpos($html, $powered)===FALSE ){
    echo die('Do not remove the powered link');
}else{
    echo $html;
}

?>
```

Comment: Let's say it's just a general grasp of how can be done. This is supposed to be implemented in a larger system and we don't know its internals. There are always tricks to enforce compliance (server settings, obfuscated code...) and there're always tricks to skip it (remove the checks from code, hide the notice with CSS...).

Comment: Erm, ok. Then the simplest answer is "echo $powered; // DO NOT REMOVE!"

Comment: There is a way around everything for those who have skill and don't give up, however, this is a good example for at least a working solution.

Comment: zaf.. actually the main of `$powered =''` protected by ioncube. the echo $powered just on the template file.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible... you can use [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) to protect your code from being altered.

Comment: That is a much better solution if protecting the code from modification important.